# RightFax WebApi Equivalent to FromGeneralFaxNumber

Tags: rightfax

I am currently looking at migrating our Sending of faxes from RightFax COM to using the RightFax WebApi and I have it mostly working. However I am having a few issues mapping certain fields to the custom coversheet we use.

In COM we are using the following fields:
FromGeneralFaxNumber & FromGeneralVoiceNumber

There doesn't seem to be an equivalent I can see for the WebApi. The documentation for WebApi mentions the use of Tags but it only mentions a few specific Keys (Notes, FromVoiceNumber, FromFaxNumber, FromName etc)

[image: Tags explaination]

I have implemented the above like so:

```
       "Tags":
           {
              "Notes": "Testing Message",
              "FromVoiceNumber": "1234",
              "FromName": "Should be From",
              "FromGeneralFaxNumber": "foo",
              "FromGeneralVoiceNumber": "bar",
              "BillingCode1": "1",

          }
```

However the FromGeneralFaxNumber and FromGeneralVoiceNumber are not working they are not mapping over to the same .pcl file that the COM object uses.

Comment: did you end up solving this? I am running into the exact same problem

Comment: Ended up mapping to some existing empty objects that were not used in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Might be something that is defined at the user level.  The SendJobs call uses userid, might be following that back to get the info there.  I hate that tags provided at submit dont persist.  I had to add my custom tags after the submit process completed.